# How to convert this php if statement in c#?

Tags: c#, php

I made a code with php and now I'm trying to convert this in C#, but it isn't working

This is the php code:

ERROR:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in connectiondb.exe
>
> Additional information: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.

In C# there's something wrong with the: if statement, but I can't find the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `if`, problem is the collection `tweedeVerzameling` it is null

Comment: I know, but it needs to be null.

Comment: @Test It is *not* "useless". Understanding what a `NullReferenceException` is will help you fix the problem in your code.

Comment: Are your sure that it needs to be null ? or just empty ? This is a huge difference. Please  look at the given link from @Nasreddine

Comment: @Test If it need to be null, why test if it contains anything ? If you meant it _could_ be null try this condition instead `if (tweedeVerzameling != null && !tweedeVerzameling.Contains(element))`

Comment: Maybe it needs to empty, hmm I'm not sure.

Comment: empty is NOT the same as null, one means there is a collection with 0 elements, the other says that there isn't even a collection

Comment: I think it needs to be empty, because when it's null, I get the wrong answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

As he mentioned in the comment, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) will explain that very clearly, Letme add few more words. In `C#` you will get NullReference Exception only when you are accessing value from null(Which means not existing).

Consider the following scenario:

> You are assigning a work to the compiler to take check/iterate a
>   collection. When compiler is going to do that process he is not able
>   to find the location that you specified. Then it returns to you with
>   the message that the specified thing is not found, i cannot proceed
>   the action. You are getting this response message from the compiler as
>   exception.

In the example that you have given, You are assigning the task "Iterate the Something that is `null`/ search something inside a memory location that is `null`. both are not possible since they are not existing in the memory.

What you can do to avoid this is, check for null before accessing the the value: consider the following changes in the signature:

```
public bool isDeelverzamelingVan(List<int> eersteVerzameling, List<int> tweedeVerzameling)
{
    if(eersteVerzameling==null || tweedeVerzameling==null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    foreach (int element in eersteVerzameling)
    {
        if (!tweedeVerzameling.Contains(element))
        {
           return false;
        }         
    }
    return true;
}
```

So the output will be `false` if anyone of the collection is null; and hence you can avoid throwing exception

Comment: I tried this, but now is restOfArray the value null:             foreach (int rid in receptIDS)
            {
                restOfArray = string.Join(",", receptIDS);
            }

            label3.Text = restOfArray.ToString();

Comment: I don't find such lines in the question

Comment: It's a lot of code

Comment: I edit it, It's not everything, but I think you don't need the another code.

Comment: At the end I implode the value.